# Deactivate Vesion-Entry in Toc-Files

Tags: faktor-ips

Is there a way to tell Faktor-IPS not to generate (or update) the productDataVersion? We change the version in the pom.xml-files each time we merge a branch to the master, so each and every branch has to deal with all the changed toc-files and relevant changes are overlooked easily.
I checked the documentation (https://doc.faktorzehn.org/faktor-ips/latest/index.html) and also the .ipsproject-file itself, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

With Faktor-IPS 24.1, the m2e plugin will replace the version in the ToC with the project's Maven coordinates, which are used to read the actual version from the JAR at runtime. See [24.1 Release Notes](https://doc.faktorzehn.org/faktor-ips/24.1/english/01_releasenotes_en/index.html#_maven_coordinates_in_table_of_contents)